# Missing @XMLElement(required = true) annotation in XML schema Java generated class

Tags: java, xml, xsd, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I do have the following XML schema:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xsd:element name="Employee" type="Employee"/>
    <xsd:complexType name="Employee">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="name"/>
            <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="registration" />
            <xsd:element type="xsd:double" name="salary" minOccurs="1"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:schema>
```

When I generate my classes using Maven I get the following result:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "employee")
public class Employee{

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String name;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String registration;
    protected double salary;
```

After the class is generated, it is used in a microservice that validates this class as a request on an endpoint.

When I change the `xsd:double` to `xsd:decimal` or `xsd:string` it becomes a proper @XMLElement which is required. However, I need it to be double and it has to be "required" for validation purposes.

The result I'm looking for is:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "employee")
public class Employee{

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String name;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String registration;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected double salary;
```

Thank you for your help.

Edit: As per the reply from M. Deinum I do remember now that primitive values are required by default. The schema within it's validation constraints allows to pass the validation when: 1) the salary field is missing and 2) when it's filled with `xsd:string` values. This is the problem I'm trying to mitigate.

Comment: Its a primitive and that is, IIRC, required by default. If you change it to `Double` (the object wrapper) you would get the additional `required=true`. But because it is a primitive that is already implied.

Comment: Many thanks @M.Deinum for reminding me that! There is one more issue I'm thinking on - the schema within it's validation constraints allows to pass the validation when: 1) the salary field is missing and 2) when it's filled with  xsd:string values. This is the problem I'm trying to mitigate.

Comment: A primitive value cannot be `null` so as such it won't ever be not set, so as stated make it a `Double` instead of a `double` in Java (you might need some JAXB configuration for that). I don't really get your additional comments? A string value (not able to convert to number) will lead to an error and if the field is missing in the XML and you validate the input it will already fail. So not sure what you are trying to say there?

Comment: @M.Deinum sorry, let me rephrase, when I send a request which is missing the "salary" field to my microservice, and it's validated against the schema, it passes through. However, the complexType (tried both, implicitly and explicitly) of Employee states that the minOccurs for this field is 1. So I'm wondering how to ensure a request with missing fields will not pass the validation.

Comment: And as I stated twice, if you want that you need the object wrapper `Double` not `double` or a `BigDecimal` a primitive won't be `null` (and depending on the validation used it validates the resulting object state and not the received XML).